# data: <fault> when return fetch request objects from method

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

When I converted my application to new technology ARC (automatic reference count) there is a fault, when I fetched from CoreData. Below is my method and calling for it:

```
NSArray *userinfo =[self checkData:self.username];

//This return fault data in array
-(NSArray*) checkData:(NSString*)loginUsername{
  id appDelegate = (id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 

  NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
  [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[appDelegate managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];

  NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSEntityDescription *userEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

  [request setEntity:userEntity];
  [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userName == %@",loginUsername ]];
  NSError *error;

  NSArray *userInfo =[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
  //NSLog(@"Number of account%@",[userInfo valueForKey:@"userName"]);

  if ([userInfo valueForKey:@"userName"] != nil && userInfo.count != 0)
    return userInfo;
  else return nil;
}
```

Here is the crash log :

```
<User: 0x12b73db0> (entity: User; id: 0x12b6dc20 <x-coredata://7388F0B7-E583-4BF0-BE64-08AD014EC583/User/p2> ; data: <fault>)
2012-12-23 10:09:18.802 test[78839:c07] -[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28ac678
2012-12-23 10:09:18.803 test[78839:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28ac678'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x277b012 0x2018e7e 0x28064bd 0x276abbc 0x276a94e 0xb4028 0x3e3be 0x1812e59 0x1810f22 0x181216a 0x1810edd 0x1811055 0x175e338 0x5d3a81 0x5d2d33 0x610e3a 0x271d8fd 0x6114bc 0x611435 0x4fb3a0 0x26fef3f 0x26fea39 0x2721734 0x2720f44 0x2720e1b 0x31027e3 0x3102668 0xc5465c 0x2806 0x2735 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: Please show your crash log.

Comment: I have update my question  with crash log

Comment: just try the code I gave first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use your AppDelegate's managedObjectContext:

So replace

```
id appDelegate = (id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[appDelegate managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];
```

to

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: Get me syntax error (No known instance method for selector 'managedObjectContext'

Comment: @wod, add `(AppDelegate *)`.

Comment: You mean my application delegation in (AppDelegate *) is it ok

Comment: @wod take a look at my answer's new version. The `AppDelegate` is your project's main delegate method. It might be `<Proj>Delegate` either.

Comment: Many Many thanks Kjuly it is work can explain your solution please

Comment: @wod u'r welcome. Cause create a `managedObjectContext`(`moc`) is not that easy as you did. You can take a look at your `AppDelegate.m` file, and you'll figure out how to create one. But generally speaking, it is better to use one `mod`. Use separate `mod` in one class is not a good idea. Multiple `moc`s might be conflict with each other. In your case, I think the `moc` you created has no persistent store (though it seems you assign it to).

Answer (score 0):

Crash log seems to say that `loginUsername` is nil. In any case you better check that it really does exist before you try to use it.